# onMouseEnter и тачпад

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouse-event

Дело в том что на блоке стоит обработчик onMouseEnter

```
 <div class="block" onMouseEnter={open}>
    <div class="list">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Логичное поведение, это то что когда мышь заходит на block, то срабатывает функция open. НО когда указатель мыши находится внутри и я прикладываю ВТОРОЙ палец на тачпаде ноутбука, то генерируется второе событие, и функция open отрабатывает снова(прямо внутри блока), что очень не нужно.

Как можно от этого избавится.

Исключать события с помощью event.target не получится, т.к в реальности внутри блока очень много других блоков.

Как можно отменить генерацию следующих событий, для других пальцев?)
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Событие `onMouseEnter` происходит, когда пользователь помещает курсор мыши в область элемента, данное событие очень спцэфично в силу своей особенности заточенности под IE, я рекомендую вам использовать другое событие.

Используйте событие `onMouseOver` - возникает однократно, когда пользователь наводит курсор мыши на элемент. Именно это событие является кроссбраузерным решением. Если необходимо, чтобы действие происходило при уходе курсора с элемента, используйте событие `onMouseOut`. Также полезно знать, что при перемещении курсора в пределах данного элемента многократно происходит событие `onMouseMove`.

Вот такой код должен работать более предсказуемо:

```
<div class="block" onMouseOver={open}>
  <div class="list">
  </div>
</div>
```

Также рекомендую проверить настройку тачпада на вашем ноутбуке, чтобы исключить проблему в настройках конкретного компьютера.